# SpringBoot - activiti - Injecting org.activiti.engine.TaskService

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, alfresco, activiti

I've created this class:

```
public class ActivitiWorkflowService  {
    

    private final TaskService taskService;

..
}
```

but I have this problem when init the project:

```
     No qualifying bean of 
type 'org.activiti.engine.TaskService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that your class has a constructor such as:

```
public class ActivitiWorkflowService  {
    

    private final TaskService taskService;

    public ActivitiWorkflowService(TaskService taskService) {
        this.taskService = taskService;
    }
}
```

The error you are getting is because Spring cannot autowire this class to the `ActivitiWorkflowService` - it probably was not defined in the `Spring` context.

Depending on the configuration you use you can either:

Define class with `@Component` or `@Service` annotation and let `@ComponentScan` do its work:

```
@Component //@Service
public TaskService {
...
}
```

or if you are using `@Configuration` class define the bean of type `TaskService`

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public TaskService taskService() {
         return new TaskService();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ActivitiWorkflowService activitiWorkflowService(TaskService taskService) {
        return new ActivitiWorkflowService(taskService);
    }
}
```